# OpenJDK installed but libjli.so not found centos 6

Tags: centos, java

I've installed openjdk-1.7.0-devel in my centos box, however, everytime I run `java --version`, I get:

```
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've already tried downloading the rpm file from oracle website and still get the error, any ideas?

If I try to locate the file it appears in a few locations in my filesystem, so I'm sure it's there.

Answer (score 1):

If using CentOS 6.3, for instance, you should just try to reinstall your Java openjdk packages. There is no reason to download anything from Oracle.

Try:

`yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

Maybe even:

`yum reinstall java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

The library you need is part of the openjdk package, and is location in: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.5.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so` on my system.

Comment: I've already tried that and still get the error, I'm also in centos 6.3.

Comment: You tried what?

Comment: Using yum to install openjdk. My libjli.so location is the same as yours, it seems that a link or reference to it is missing somewhere else.

Comment: I suggested `yum reinstall`...  Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, I even removed it and then reinstalled also

Comment: can you print here the output of the dir "ls -al jre/lib/amd64/jli/". Else I would suggest to download the jdk from original source and install it. Yum installation have some problems with jdk and you might face it later too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command and it will work:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib64/gcj-4.4.6/libjvm.so /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/lib/amd64/client/libjvm.so
```

If by any chance it doesn't work, then give me the output for following commands and I will update my answer:

```
 # ls -l /usr/lib64/
 # ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/
```

Comment: Used ```cd /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf; ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/lib/arm/jli/libjli.so; ldconfig``` on an ARM device (Pelya's Debian android app, which creates a fakechroot Debian environment on an unrooted phone).  This made java work for me.